# SVN authentication with mod_authn_dbd works but other svn users can see other repositories

Tags: svn, apache2, virtualhost

As the title already says the SVN authentication works fine with mod_authn_dbd and MySQL but if I log in with the credentials for /repos/testrepo I am able to switch to /repos/{any-other-existing-repo} in the browser and see others repos after successful login. What is wrong with my configuration?

Apache2 VirtualHost:

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=127.0.0.1 port=3306 dbname=svndb user=svnuser pass=svnpass"
DBDMin 1
DBDKeep 8
DBDMax 20
DBDExptime 200

<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/repos/

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repository"
  AuthBasicProvider dbd
  AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user = %s"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

MySQL Database:

```
"svndb.users"
  id (int)
  user (varchar)
  password (varchar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem. First one is to change the SVNParentPath directive to SVNPath, and only point to your /var/www/svn/repos/testrepo. The other solution is to enable authz_svn_module (per-directory access control) and add authorization file using the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive. The reason your configuration is allowing access to all repositories under the /var/www/svn/repos path is because the SVNParentPath shares child directories. This is from the SVNParentPath docs:

> Specifies the location in the filesystem of a parent directory whose
>   child directories are Subversion repositories. In a configuration
>   block for a Subversion repository, either this directive or SVNPath
>   must be present, but not both.

Solution 1:

```
...
<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/www/svn/repos/testrepo

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repository"
  AuthBasicProvider dbd
  AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user = %s"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Solution 2:

```
...
<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/repos/
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/access-file.txt

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repository"
  AuthBasicProvider dbd
  AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user = %s"
  Require valid-user
</Location>

====== access-file.txt ======

[groups]
admins = joe, kee
developers = marry
deployers = build

[testrepo:/]
@admins = rw
@deployers = r
@developers = rw

[someotherrepo:/]
@admins = rw
@developers =
@deployers =
zack = rw
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the MySQL authentication with SVNParentPath? For example with Require directive in a Limit section? I don't want to create entries for each user. Also I want to give users self-service for password changes...

Comment: You can keep this the way it looks like right now. Basic HTTP authentication is not related to SVN module in any way. I just don't think there is a clean way to keep authorization inside of the DB. One solution is to have a table structure with authorization data, and than dump that to filesystem periodically.